# gdcm libs link order

Tags: qt, qmake, gdcm

I am trying to link my Qt app to gdcm library.
When I build it, I get several errors like this: undefined reference to 'gdcm::System::FileExists(char const*)'.
I think the problem comes from the link order specified in my .pro file:

```
LIBS += -lgdcmMSFF \
    -lgdcmCommon \
    -lgdcmDICT \
    -lgdcmDSED \
    -lgdcmIOD \
    -lgdcmMEXD \
    -lgdcmcharls \
    -lgdcmexpat \
    -lgdcmjpeg12 \
    -lgdcmjpeg16 \
    -lgdcmjpeg8 \
    -lgdcmopenjpeg \
    -lgdcmzlib \
    -lgdcmgetopt \
    -lsocketxx \
```

Can anybody provide me the correct order for gdcm libs ?
Thanks

Comment: `gdcmCommon` shared object contains definition of `gdcm::System::FileExists(char const*)` symbol. I don't really think order matters.

Comment: order does matter when you are linking static libs

Comment: possible duplicate of [Qt + GDCM problems with the libs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19738421/qt-gdcm-problems-with-the-libs)