# Qt + GDCM problems with the libs

Tags: qt, gdcm

I'm trying to use the library gdcm in my project. However I'm with some problem.

gdcmGlobal.cxx:-1: error: undefined reference to `gdcm::System::FileIsDirectory(char const*)'
gdcmGlobal.cxx:-1: error: undefined reference to`gdcm::System::FileIsDirectory(char const*)'
gdcmGlobal.cxx:-1: error: undefined reference to `gdcm::System::FileExists(char const*)'
:-1: error: C:\Program_Library\gdcm-2.0.18-mingw32\bin/libgdcmDICT.a(gdcmGlobal.cxx.obj): bad reloc address 0xf in section`.text$*ZNK4gdcm7Modules7IsEmptyEv[*_ZNK4gdcm7Modules7IsEmptyEv]'

I included the libs:

> LIBS += -L"C:\Program_Library\gdcm-2.0.18-mingw32\bin" \
>           -L"C:\Program_Library\gdcm-2.0.18-mingw32\bin\libgdcmMSFF.a" \
>           -L"C:\Program_Library\gdcm-2.0.18-mingw32\bin\libgdcmCommon.a"\
>           -L"C:\Program_Library\gdcm-2.0.18-mingw32\bin\libgdcmDICT.a"\
>           -L"C:\Program_Library\gdcm-2.0.18-mingw32\bin\libgdcmDSED.a"\
>           -L"C:\Program_Library\gdcm-2.0.18-mingw32\bin\libgdcmexpat.a"\
>           -L"C:\Program_Library\gdcm-2.0.18-mingw32\bin\libgdcmIOD.a"\
>           -L"C:\Program_Library\gdcm-2.0.18-mingw32\bin\libgdcmjpeg8.a"\
>           -L"C:\Program_Library\gdcm-2.0.18-mingw32\bin\libgdcmjpeg12.a"\
>           -L"C:\Program_Library\gdcm-2.0.18-mingw32\bin\libgdcmjpeg16.a"\
>           -L"C:\Program_Library\gdcm-2.0.18-mingw32\bin\libgdcmopenjpeg.a"\
>           -L"C:\Program_Library\gdcm-2.0.18-mingw32\bin\libgdcmzlib.a"\
>           -L"C:\Program_Library\gdcm-2.0.18-mingw32\bin\libgdcmcharls.a"\
>           -L"C:\Program_Library\gdcm-2.0.18-mingw32\bin\libgdcmgetopt.a"
>
> LIBS += -lgdcmMSFF -lgdcmCommon -lgdcmDICT -lgdcmDSED -lgdcmexpat
>   -lgdcmIOD -lgdcmjpeg8 -lgdcmjpeg12 -lgdcmjpeg16 -lgdcmopenjpeg -lgdcmzlib -lgdcmcharls -lgdcmgetopt

Anybody would know what is happening?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Qt 5.1 uses g++ 4.8 and I used g++ 4.6 to compile gdcm! That is the problem! However when I included:

> include < gdcmGlobal.h>

appear this error:

> gdcmGlobal.cxx:-1: error: undefined reference to
>   `gdcm::System::FileIsDirectory(char const*)'

but when I remove: include < gdcmGlobal.h>, compiles!